# ROS wandering / exploring robot program?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, exploration, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using my bot to assemble a 3d map of it's surroundings using RTABMAP.

Is there another ROS program I can have subscribe to the output of RTABMAP which then autonomously explores unknown areas of the environment until a loop closure or until everything is known?

3d navigation is preferred but I'll take what I can get!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243924/ros-wandering-/-exploring-robot-program?/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should take a look at the package [cam_exploration](https://github.com/UbiCALab/cam_exploration).

---

Originally posted by [schrottulk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28444/schrottulk/) with karma: 63 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-12-21**:
Interesting, this might be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the referral.